# Sharepoint Issues with Checking Out Documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, check-out

We have a unique problem, We have several of our users that can check out signed in documents, although they are in the same permission group as other users.

The link that you use to check out the document isn't even available. Acts like a read only file.  Is there something that we can do to fix this? We have looked at most all the TechNet type sites for more info. However, we have yet to run into anyone with this problem.

Any possible solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

0down vote

There is one other instance where this error happens that is not explained here. If you have version control turned on and have not set limits (Major and Minor). Then the upper limit for the drafts (Minor) versions is 0.511 . Once you hit this number you will not be able to check out the document. The reason for this is that the Version number is stored internally on SQL as a 16bit number and since 256 is the largest number for 8bit integers 512 is the largest for 16bit. (Okay that's enough for the technical stuff) To get around this problem just publish the version 0.511 so that it becomes version 1.0 and there your done.

The next thing you should do is set the limits for the major and minor versions.. In my case 200 minors covers about 2 months and 100 majors would help keep that even longer if needed. Then educate your users on the use of Major (Published) and Minor (Drafts). This will help keep your version control managable.

Happy Versioning...